Tracing execution order
I am new to JS and am trying to figure out the execution order when the code has microtasks. I know the theory behind it, that the microtasks are pushed to the call stack from the queue when the stack is "empty" (i.e. when there is only global context on it).
For example, in the global context we have two consecutive loops:
for(let i = 0; i<1000; i++){
    console.log(i);
};

for(let i = 0; i<1000; i++){
    console.log(i);
};

Is it true that before, after and during the execution of the for-loops the condition of the stack being empty is fulfilled? If yes, why is the microtask (res)=> { console.log(res)} in the following code not executed between the last two loops if by that time it is in the queue and the call stack is empty?
const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, _){
    resolve('microtask2');
});

for(let i = 0; i<1000; i++){
    console.log(i);
};

promise.then((res)=> {
    console.log(res);
)};

for(let i = 0; i<1000; i++){
    console.log(i);
};

for(let i = 0; i<1000; i++){
    console.log(i);
};

Here's how I see the execution order:

The executor function inside the promise's constructor calls resolve() and settles the promise immediately.
A loop is executed.
then() is evoked, it's context put on the call stack (on top of the global context)
The callback inside then() is registered somewhere in the browser's environment.
then context pops off the stack.
Another loop is executed, as the callback from then() was only registered and is not yet in the queue (or does it go to the queue immediately?)
Now that the loop is finished and the call stack is empty, event loop picks up the callback from the queue tosses it to the call stack and executes (I know it is not the case and the callback is going to be printed last, but I don't know why)
The last loop is executed

By the step 7 all the condition for the callback to be executed are fulfilled:
a) there is nothing on the stack
b) no synchronous code is running
c) the callback is waiting in the queue
Why is the callback sitting in the queue until the final loop is executed if there are plenty of oportunities to be executed between the loops?

Edited to address Scott Marcus' commentary
The whole question was inspired by the unexpected behaviour (well, unexpected for me, at least) of the following code:
const timer = setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('set timeout');
}, 0);

new Promise(function(resolve, _){
    try{   
        resolve('microtask1');
    }
    catch(err){
        console.error(`caught an ${err}`);
    }
}).then((res)=>{
    console.log(res);
});
console.log('synchronous code 1');

const result = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos`);

console.log('synchronous code 2');

At the beginning I thought that micro-/macrotasks are only executed once the last synchronous line of code in a file is executed (in this case, console.log('synchronous code 2')), and that's exactly what I have been seeing until I executed an await statement outside an async function.
If you run the code above, you will get the following output:

If I wrap the await statement in an async function like this:
let result;
const timer = setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('set timeout');
}, 0);

new Promise(function(resolve, _){
    try{   
        resolve('microtask1');
    }
    catch(err){
        console.error(`caught an ${err}`);
    }
}).then((res)=>{
    console.log(res);
});
console.log('synchronous code 1');

(async function(){
    result = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos`);
})();

console.log('synchronous code 2');

...the output will be different (exactly what I would expect):

I've been trying to figure out why top-level await exhibits this behaviour for 11 hours now, and I'm still nowhere near the answer. If there is a chance you could cast some light on this, I'd be beyond grateful.

What you are describing is asynchronous API calls. JavaScript runs in a single-threaded environment. When an asynchronous method call is made, it is handled outside of that runtime. When the runtime stack is empty, those asynchronous tasks can push their results back into the JS runtime environment  by looking at the event queue to see what is next up for processing.

@ScotMarcus, Thank you for the explanation! I've edited the question to add - what I thought would be - relevant details. Could you please take another look at it?

Rather than me giving you an explanation, take a look at this video, which I think is one of the clearest explanations and demonstrations of how this works.

FWIW javascript's execution order is just like any other programming language: C/C++, Java, Python etc. There is no difference. The biggest difference is that javascript has a lot of asynchronous APIs but other languages like C/C++, Java, Python etc. also have asynchronous APIs and behave exactly the same as javascript only that there are not a lot of them and most people don't use them.

@slebetman C/C++/Java also have multithreaded execution with preemption, which Python and JavaScript typically don't use. And using asynchronous features is not part of the runtime environment, like in JS, you usually have to run the event loop yourself, which makes it much more traceable.

@Bergi C/C++ also have singlethreaded asynchronous I/O (see the POSIX select() function) but like I mentioned very few people have ever used it. Nginx and Apache developers as well as browser developers are some of those who've written C++ the way we write node.js code with event-oriented async I/O. To be fair, javascript in the browser and node.js also have multithreading via web workers and worker threads.


Is it true that before, after and during the execution of the for-loops the condition of the stack being empty is fulfilled?

No. The global execution context is still on the stack. The whole code runs to completion, only afterwards the stack becomes empty and asynchronous tasks can run.

that's exactly what I have been seeing until I executed an await statement outside an async function.

Until the await, the module evaluation execution context is on the stack. Once the execution reaches the await, the execution of the module code is suspended, and the context is popped from the stack. With TLA, there's nothing below it, and the stack becomes empty; in an async function it would just return (the promise) from the call.
Once the promise resolves later, the execution of the context is resumed, in its own asynchronous microtask.

This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much, Bergi! It really felt as if await used some technology similar to generator functions under the hood: (1) pause the execution of the function's body until the promise is settled => (2) return control to the caller => (3) once promise is settled - resume the execution of the function. Now it makes perfect sense. Thank you again!
